# Initialize Varbinary datatype in MySQL

Tags: mysql, varbinary

In MySQL, I want to declare a default value to a `varbinary` column. How do I achieve it ?

```
DECLARE result varbinary(8000);
SET result   = 0x;
```

I used `select CHAR_LENGTH(00101)` and it gives me a result 3. I am expecting my result to be 5 (number of characters in string). To measure the length of a `varbinary` string, how do I do it ?

Comment: `CHAR_LENGTH(00101)` is `CHAR_LENGTH(101)` which is 3. `CHAR_LENGTH('00101')` is 5. Try: `SELECT 00101`.

Comment: ThnQ, it works. Any idea on How to declare a varbinary column and set a default binary value !

Answer (score 3):

When you create your table you can specify a default. For binary data you should probably express it as a hex string, `0x...` style:

```
CREATE TABLE binary_default (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  binary_data VARBINARY(8000) DEFAULT 0x010203
);
```

You can test this works with:

```
INSERT INTO binary_default VALUES ()
```

Then fetch, but as it's binary, you might want a hex view:

```
SELECT id, HEX(binary_data) FROM binary_default
```

Comment: Creation of a Table with varbinary is not the intention. 
I am trying to write a function. so i want to declare and initialize a variable with varbinary. 
After that i want to perform some computation on it. 
For Example:
CREATE FUNCTION test
DECLARE result varbinary(8000);
SET result   = 0x; 
begin 
select result = result + 00101; 
return result;
end;  
MySQL is throwing a error at initilizing part, how do i overcome it and perform the computation ?

Comment: What does `00101` even mean in this context?

Comment: Its a binary format'00101', that i want to add to 0x(result varibale) which i initialized

Comment: I know what you're trying to do, but `SELECT 00101` proves that MySQL has no idea what you're talking about. You need to use a notation that MySQL understands or this will never work. That's why I used the `0x` notation.